# Can anyone tell me what version of opengl is this?

Tags: c++, opengl

Can you tell me what version of opengl is this code written in ?

```
//The triangles to the highest and deepest vertices:
for (j = 0; j< (PointsPerRow-1); j++)
{
    IndexVect.push_back(j);
    IndexVect.push_back(j+1);
    IndexVect.push_back((PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow);
}
IndexVect.push_back(j);
IndexVect.push_back(0);
IndexVect.push_back((PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow);

for (j = 0; j< (PointsPerRow-1); j++)
{
    IndexVect.push_back((PointRows-3)*PointsPerRow+j);
    IndexVect.push_back((PointRows-3)*PointsPerRow+j+1);
    IndexVect.push_back((PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow+1);
}
IndexVect.push_back((PointRows-3)*PointsPerRow+j);
IndexVect.push_back((PointRows-3)*PointsPerRow);
IndexVect.push_back((PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow+1);
Indices = new GLuint[IndexVect.size()];  //allocate the required memory
for (i = 0; i < IndexVect.size(); i++)
{
    Indices[i] = IndexVect[i];
}
NumIndices = IndexVect.size();
IndexVect.clear();  //no longer needed, takes only memory
```

}

this is a vertex array core tell me in which version it is written?

Comment: I see no OpenGL specific code here.... My guess is 4.x because they seem to be using an index vector for an IBO maybe?

Comment: Based on the code you posted it would be hard to identify this as OpenGL in the first place, let alone give a specific version for it. Can you try building this with the latest OpenGL library and see if it works?

Comment: GLuint are... very common in OpenGL. If you are trying to retrieve which version your code is running on, you can try:
    glGetString(GL_VERSION);
And that will tell you which version of OpenGL is running. If you want to know which version you need to run this code, the answer is all OpenGL versions I know of can do this.

Comment: Sorry but push_back is a C++ method, not an opengl method http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/

Comment: wait i will add a funtion here

Comment: void Display(void)
{
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 glLoadIdentity();
 glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-4.0);
 glRotatef(yRotated, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
 DrawSphere();
 glFlush();   //Finish rendering
 glutSwapBuffers();
}

Comment: That looks like OpenGL 2.1 possibly because of the use of `glLoadIdentity()` and `glTranslatef()` but it's possible it's any version as those functions were deprecated but still supported in just about any version.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you would provide some background and tell us why you need to know which version this was written for. For example, are you having trouble compiling it? Where did this code come from? This guessing game isn't helping anyone.

Comment: no its because i want to write the same code using Vertex ARRAY in any opengl prior to 3+

Comment: @JesusRamos Having an index list into a vertex list predates 4.0 by a long time, just the memory locations changed.

Comment: @josefx True, my best guess was the setup for an IBO or VBO but it could be anything really, not much info to go on.

Answer (score 3):

The first piece of code has no specific OpenGL version to it, except for the GLuint everything is standard c++ (IndexVect looks like a std::vector) and GLuint is a basic number type (like unsigned int, unsigned short,...) used in every OpenGL version.

The reason the code has no OpenGL calls is that it only defines the structure of an object on the CPU, it does nothing to copy the data to the GPU nor does it render anything.

```
void Display(void) { 
       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
       glLoadIdentity();
       glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-4.0);
       glRotatef(yRotated, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
       DrawSphere();
       glFlush();
       //Finish rendering
       glutSwapBuffers(); }
```

That is OpenGL <= 2.0, the glLoadIdentity(),glTranslatef and glRotatef methods Operate on the now deprecated matrix stacks.